# my jupyter notebook is pasting unncessary program lines inbetween

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

when I try to write any code jupyter notebook automatically paste any irrelevant / sometimes relevant program between the program, but I want to stop this shit, because it is irritating me. suggestions are different things. but this issue has arrived in my notebook for the past few days.[you can see in this link exactly what happening in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKF4S.png)
how can I get rid of it? please help me out. The error lines are in green color whereas normal program looks like this[See this line in grey color is suggested by notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdVHL.png)

I am just confused. I don't know how it started. I didn't get any solution on it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

looks like https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-notebooks-annoying-grey-text-auto-show/16886/5, This is most likely a browser issue, what browser are you using? any extentions that could cause this? maybe try switching browsers?